# how to add socks5 auth to a net.Conn in Golang?

Tags: go, tcp, socks

How i can create a net.Conn that connect to a Socks5 server with User/Password authentication

```
conn,err:=net.Dial("tcp","user:pass@ip_addr:port")
```

Comment: Use https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/proxy or similar package.

Answer (score 1):

```
    d, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", surl.Host, auth, forwrder)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    conn, err := d.Dial("tcp", testURL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    import (
        "net"   
        "time"
        "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
    )

    auth := proxy.Auth{User: "username", Password: "password"}
    dailer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", "socks5_ip:port", &auth, &net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   60 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
    })
    conn, err := dailer.Dial("tcp", "target_ip:port")
```